# I have tablayout with viewpager how to hide Bottombar in 4 Fragments except first Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a tablayout, viewpager with 4 fragments. 
I  added bottombar in my MainActivity so it was showing all fragments.
I just  want bottombar only in first fragment.
How to hide bottombar for other 3 fragments?

This is MainActivity:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    bottombar = BottomBar.attach(MainActivity.this,savedInstanceState);
    bottombar.setItemsFromMenu(R.menu.bottom_bar_menu, new OnMenuTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMenuItemSelected(int itemId) {
            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.about_us:
                    About_Us about_us = new About_Us();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,About_Us.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.contact_us:
                    SquareFragment squareFragment = new SquareFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,squareFragment).commit();
                    //squareFragment.updateColor(Color.parseColor(colors[1]));
                    break;
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected contact_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                case R.id.donate_us:
                    donate_us_Fragment donate_us_fragment = new donate_us_Fragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame,donate_us_fragment).commit();
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"selected donate_us",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    bottombar.setActiveTabColor("#C2185B");

    //Initializing the tablayout
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home").setIcon(R.drawable.home_selector));

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News").setIcon(R.drawable.news_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Videos").setIcon(R.drawable.video_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("PodCasts").setIcon(R.drawable.podcast_selector));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("More").setIcon(R.drawable.more_selector));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    //tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    //Initializing viewPager
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    //Creating our pager adapter
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    //Adding adapter to pager
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
 }

 }
```

This is ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

//integer to count number of tabs
int tabCount;
BottomBar bottombar;

//Constructor to the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount) {
    super(fm);
    //Initializing tab count
    this.tabCount = tabCount;
}

//Overriding method getItem
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    //Returning the current tabs
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Home_Fragment();
        case 1:
            News_Fragment news_fragment = new News_Fragment();
            bottombar.hide();
            return news_fragment;
        case 2:
         Video_Fragment video_fragment =  new Video_Fragment();
            return video_fragment;

        case 3:
            return new PodCasts_Fragment();
        case 4:
            return new More_Fragment();
    }
    return null;
}

//Overriden method getCount to get the number of tabs
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
```

See this image below:

[image]

Comment: its very easy set layout_weight=1 fragment container and set bottom layout visibility Gone when select other 3 tabs

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
  if(tab.getPosition == 0 )
    bottomBar.hide();
  super.onTabSelected(tab);
}
```

And remove the

```
bottomBar.hide();
```

from the `getItem()` in the fragment.

Comment: @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        //Returning the current tabs
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Home_Fragment();
            case 1:
                News_Fragment news_fragment = new News_Fragment();
                return news_fragment;
            case 2:
             Video_Fragment video_fragment =  new Video_Fragment();
                return video_fragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

Comment: in case 0: add the statement to hide the bar before returning the new fragment

Comment: i have added bottombar.hide(); method in case 0: but getting NullpointerException

Comment: It means you're not instantiating the bottombar before creating the viewerPage

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar.hide()' on a null object reference this is the error

Comment: Exactly, where do you create your BottomBar?

Comment: i have initialized bottombar but getting this error

Comment: am creating bottombar in MainActivity

Comment: Your getItem is being called before you initialize your bottomBar. That's why

Comment: and put hide method in ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: Edit your post and post the full code of creation of bottom bar & of the page adapter please

Comment: i initialzed bottombar before called getItem...but again got same error

Comment: when i put bottom.hide() method in setonTabSelectedListener method..then All fragments Are hide....i want hide all fragments except first fragment

Comment: That's why you need to check the tab.getPosition first.

Comment: No prob, glad it worked :) Mark as correct please :)

Answer (score 0):

this is correct code

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            if(tab.getPosition() == 0){
                bottombar.show();
            }else
            if(tab.getPosition() == 1){
                bottombar.hide();
            }else
            if(tab.getPosition() == 2){
                bottombar.hide();
            }else
            if(tab.getPosition() == 3){
                bottombar.hide();
            }
            super.onTabSelected(tab);
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            super.onTabUnselected(tab);
            //tab.getIcon().setAlpha(127);
        }
    });
}
```

}